# How to avoid all sources of a MediatorLiveData calling the same function?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack, event-driven

**Introduction to the problem:**
When using the `MediatorLiveData` that android has added with android jetpack, I find myself often calling the same function from every source. This can for example be because, whenever a source is updated, I have to check if it has an influence, or if another source is more important. An example in code (Kotlin, but shouldn't matter):

```
val isHovered = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isSelected = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

val color = MediatorLiveData<Int>().apply { 
    addSource(isHovered) { updateColor() }
    addSource(isSelected) { updateColor() }
}

fun updateColor() {
    if (isHovered.value == true)
        color.value = Color.GREEN
    else if (isSelected.value == true)
        color.value = Color.RED
    else
        color.value = Color.GRAY
}
```

The item is green when hovering, red when selected and not hovering and gray otherwise. When isSelected changes to true, I still need to check whether it is hovering, before changing the color to red. Also when isHovering changes to false, I need to check whether it is selected before changing the color to grey. So the easiest is one function that takes all the variables into account and sets the color accordingly.

**My problem:**
When the MediatorLiveData changes from inactive to active, because the view is moved to the foreground, it can happen that the function `updateColor` is called multiple times, for each source that changed. This is unnecessary because each call already takes all variables into account. As this function can be quite complex and there can be many sources, **is there a way to avoid calling it multiple times for the same states of the source LiveDatas?**

Comment: Why do you need `apply` function?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky That is a Kotlin thing which allows me to directly use an object while also returning it. You could just as well call the `addSource` functions from the Constructor.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and came up with the following solution. First, gather values from all sources to one value:

```
data class State(val isHovered: Boolean, val isSelected: Boolean)

private val state = MediatorLiveData<State>().apply {
    fun update() {
        value = State(isHovered.value ?: false, isSelected.value ?: false)
    }

    addSource(isHovered) { update() }
    addSource(isSelected) { update() }
}
```

Then I created an extension function to emit only distinct values

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.distinct(): LiveData<T> = MediatorLiveData<T>().apply {
    var wasSet = false
    addSource(this@distinct) {
        // Update value if it has been changed or it's the first time the method called
        // Because value is null by default it will not be set to null again, leaving the live data in [value not set] state
        if (value != it || !wasSet) {
            value = it
            wasSet = true
        }
    }
}
```

So when observing `state.distinct()` you will get updated values only when it's really changed.

Sometimes also another extension can be useful:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.squashUpdates() = MediatorLiveData<T>().apply {
    addSource(this@squashUpdates) {
        postValue(it)
    }
}
```

Normally, when `LiveData` value is changed, it notifies all observers immediately in the same stack frame. Let's say you have a `MediatorLiveData` and change values of multiple sources like:

```
isHovered.value = true
isSelected.value = true
```

`state` value will be changed two times in a row `State(true, false)` and `State(true, true)`. They both will be dispatched, even when using `distinct` from above, because values are actually different. `squashUpdates` helps in this case by delaying dispatch to the end of the stack frame, dispatching last value only.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple calls, you should send only new updates from your `LiveData` instances. To achieve this, you can use `SingleLiveEvent`:

> A lifecycle-aware observable that sends only new updates after
>   subscription, used for events like navigation and Snackbar messages.
>
> This avoids a common problem with events: on configuration change
>   (like rotation) update can be emitted if the observer is active. This
>   LiveData only calls the observable if there's an explicit call to
>   setValue() or call().
>
> Note that only one observer is going to be notified of changes.

Comment: The SingleLiveEvent is a pattern I am using, however it does not work if all sources LiveDatas have new values. The common function will still be called too often.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to prevent `isHovered` or `isSelected` from emitting items, but you can pervent `color` from emitting multiple items of same type. The idea is to change the color only when the current color is not equal to the new color.

```
fun updateColor() {
    var newColor: Color?    

    if (isHovered.value == true)
        newColor = Color.GREEN
    else if (isSelected.value == true)
        newColor = Color.RED
    else
        newColor = Color.GRAY

    if (color.value != newColor) {
        color.value = newColor!!
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I already have a helper function that only updates when it is actually changed. But that doesn't prevent the expensive function from running twice